# 0(12) : error C7565: assignment to varying 'var'

Tags: opengl, glsl, lwjgl

I cant figure out how to set the fs_in.tc var in glsl

It gives me this error:

```
0(12) : error C7565: assignment to varying 'tc'
```

fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) out vec4 colour;

in DATA {
    vec2 tc;
} fs_in;

uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform int top;

void main() {
    if (top == 1)
        fs_in.tc.y = 1.0 - fs_in.tc.y;
    colour = texture(tex, fs_in.tc);
    if (colour.w < 1.0)
    discard;
}
```

Comment: `fs_in` is an input variable. Just do `colour = texture(tex, top == 1 ? vec2(fs_in.tc.x, 1.0-fs_in.tc.y) : fs_in.tc)`

Comment: @Rabbid76 I know but can I change input vars?

Comment: No, you cannot, which is evident from the error message *"0(12) : error C7565: assignment to varying 'var'"*

Comment: Sorry I didn't give enough details what I meant was is there any way to change input vars? but you already gave me an answer @Rabbid76